# I figure it out myself

Tags: php, mysql

in the updates.. with my code above, it is working if i only choose 1 row but when i have chosen more than 1 row, the value in the last row that i inserted is the only value that mysql is using to updates all rows. 2 yes it is intended. i need it for my updates, 3rd sorry, but i am using CSS though i will clean my code after i finish my program, im just stack here

This is my parent window HTML code

JAVASCRIPT

```
function MM_openBrWindow(theURL,winName,features) { //v2.0
  var chkValue = "";
  var counter = "";
    for (var i=0; i < document.myForm.chkbox.length; i++)
      {
          if (document.myForm.chkbox[i].checked)
          {
            chkValue = chkValue + document.myForm.chkbox[i].value + " ";
          }
          counter ++;
       }
  var queryString = "&chkValue=" + chkValue; 
  //  location = "featuredaction.php" + queryString
  //var queryString = "id=" + id;
  var theURL = theURL + queryString;
  //var tbreceiptno= document.getElementById('checkbox').value;
  window.open(theURL,winName,features);
}
```

I think i will fgure it out my own thanks everyone..

Comment: 1st of all i didn't understand the question. Where you are facing problem? If its in the UPDATE statement, what database library you are using? 2nd, sometimes you are assigning variables from post variable value. On another time, you are assigning post variable to other variables. Is it intended? 3rd, use css and get rid of those ugly looking markups.

Comment: in the updates.. with my code above, it is working if i only choose 1 row but when i have chosen more than 1 row, the value in the last row that i inserted is the only value that mysql is using to updates all rows. 2 yes it is intended. i need it for my updates, 3rd sorry, but i am using CSS though i will clean my code after i finish my program, im just stack here :(

Answer (score 2):

You have fault in your second line `$chkValueArr=explode(" ", $chkValue);`. You dont have to explode it. You already got an Array of checkbox value when you wrote `$chkValue=$_GET['chkValue'];` Assuming your HTML form is something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkValue[]" value="val 1">
<input type="checkbox" name="chkValue[]" value="val 2">
<input type="checkbox" name="chkValue[]" value="val 3">
```

You can loop over all checkbox values by:

```
foreach($chkValue as $chk) 
{
    echo $chk;
}
```

This will print `val 1`, `val 3` if you selected those checkboxes in your form.

*You can check the array by writing* `print_r($chkValue)`

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.. I need to explode array because it isnt comes from check boxes,  edited my post that i guess to clear things up.. $chkValue=$_GET['chkValue']; echo $chkValue; will output val1 val2 val3

Comment: @phpWorth I dont see any checkbox in your HTML code with name='chkValue'. Where is it? And why are you getting space separated values instead of array?

Comment: ooopss sorry... i just read your post.. it is actually came from the parent window where i query all the list in my database. then i will check/choose the data that i needed to update and i passed it on the child window.

Comment: `<td><input name="psr_qtyR" id="psr_qtyR" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $psr_qtyR; ?>" />
              <?php echo $psr_qtyR; ?>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input name="psr_qtyRo" id="psr_qtyRo" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $psr_qtyI; ?>" />
              <?php echo ($psr_qtyI*1); ?>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><?php echo $psr_num; ?></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" id="chkbox" value="<?php echo $psr_id; ?>" />
           </td>
        
          <?php } ?>
        </tr>`

Comment: function `MM_openBrWindow(theURL,winName,features) { //v2.0
  var chkValue = "";
  var counter = "";
 for (var i=0; i < document.myForm.chkbox.length; i++)
   {
    if (document.myForm.chkbox[i].checked)
    {
   chkValue = chkValue + document.myForm.chkbox[i].value + " ";
    }
    counter ++;
    }
  var queryString = "&chkValue=" + chkValue; 
  //  location = "featuredaction.php" + queryString
  //var queryString = "id=" + id;
  var theURL = theURL + queryString;
  //var tbreceiptno= document.getElementById('checkbox').value;
  window.open(theURL,winName,features);
} `

Comment: @phpWorth Please put your HTML and javascript code in your question.

Comment: i edited already, i hope u can help me to figure it out.  :)

Comment: I need to automatically updates 1 or more rows in my sql,